# Derivative of composition of vector-valued functions.

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^{n}}$ and $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable. Then,
>
> $$(fF)' = f'F + fF'$$

To prove this, I tried using the definition of derivative:

**LHS**: $$(foF)' = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{(foF)(t+h)-(foF)(h)}{h}$$

**RHS**: $$f'F + fF' = \left(\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}\right)(F) + f\left(\lim_{h\to0} \frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h}\right)$$

I have no idea where to go from here. Am I wrong to use the definition of the derivative to get this identity?

Comment: Notice that $f\circ F \neq f \cdot F$. Also it might be helpful to write the derivative in higher dimensions with $DF$ for example, to make more explicit that the Derivative is actually a matrix at any given point.

Comment: So should I be using the dot product instead of composition of functions?

Comment: Notice that composition isn't even defined this way, you could only do $F \circ f$ but then you would get a chain rule and not a product rule. Also notice that you can not have a dot product because the one function is just a scalar function. In this case the dot really just means scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F=(F_1,...,F_n)$ with $F_j: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R.$ Then

$fF=(fF_1,...,fF_n)$ with $fF_j: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R.$

Now apply the usual product rule to $fF_j$ and you will get the desired result.